Laravel Dusk test cases are failing after upgrading to 11.x from 10.x
I have upgraded the Laravel to 11.x from 10.x, after upgrading my all Dusk test cases are failing with the following error
Received Mockery_1_Illuminate_Console_OutputStyle::askQuestion(), but no expectations were specified

  at vendor\symfony\console\Style\SymfonyStyle.php:231
    227▕     }
    228▕
    229▕     public function confirm(string $question, bool $default = true): bool
    230▕     {
  ➜ 231▕         return $this->askQuestion(new ConfirmationQuestion($question, $default));
    232▕     }
    233▕
    234▕     public function choice(string $question, array $choices, mixed $default = null, bool $multiSelect = false): mixed
    235▕     {

  1   vendor\symfony\console\Style\SymfonyStyle.php:231
  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\InteractsWithIO.php:142

I have tried upgrading the following packages to it latest version as of today, still it is giving me the same error.
"laravel/framework": "^11.21",
"laravel/dusk": "^8.2.4",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.6.12",

Any thought why it is giving me this error?
